# not authorized to create an event

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm building the code to create a new event for google calendar. Actually inserted data are static since I focus on using Google API.
If I run my code I get that:

> "domain": "global", "reason": "insufficientPermissions", "message": "Insufficient Permission"

I'm able to read an event list but not to create the event:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/calendar-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/../client_secret.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR)
));

function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
  $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
  if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv('HOMEDRIVE') . getenv('HOMEPATH');
  }
  return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
  $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
  $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');

  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
  } else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
    print 'Enter verification code: ';
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
  }
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  }
  return $client;
}
// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);


$calendarId='primary';



// $calendarId should contain the calendar id found on the settings page of the calendar
/*
$events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($events);
echo '</pre>';
*/
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2018-01-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'recurrence' => array(
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ),
  'attendees' => array(
    array('email' => 'aaa@gmail.com'),
    array('email' => 'bbb@gmail.com'),
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));

$calendarId = 'primary';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For further reference and for those who will face the same issue: if you generate a new token for full acccess and you already have a valid one for read only you have to delete the firts one and generate the new one.

I didn't and the valid token was never replaced so I kept having only read only access.